# Post-2000 F&SF story about a writer who steals ideas by shaking hands with other authors

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this one in F&SF (or maybe Asimov's) in the early 2000s I think - the main character is an aspiring writer who goes to a book signing by a very famous writer - one who is known for writing in a very wide variety of styles and subgenres. The main character has a brief conversation with the famous author ("where do you get your ideas?) and shakes his hand. Afterwards, the main character can't think of any ideas, and comes to the realization that famous author is an idea vampire, which explains the variety of his output.

Comment: somewhat reminds me of the old twilight zone where the guy can exchange physical or other attributes with other people just by both sides agreeing to the trade. once he trades his own broken arm for cash and it works -- his room mate in the hospital, an old man who indeed suddenly has a broken arm sadly realizes that at his age, it won't heal for a very long time -- a creepy Zone for sure.

Comment: Sounds like a biography of China Miéville. (viz. genre spanning) :D

Comment: I'm going to say pretty close to 2000 - say between 2000 and 2010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

["Pleased to Meetcha"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?296521), a short short story by [Ken Altabef](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?51211) published in [*The Magazine of Fantasy & Science Fiction*, August 2006](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?51211), apparently never reprinted. The text is available at [the author's website](http://www.kenaltabef.com/short-stories.html).

Synopsis from NESFA's [Recursive Science Fiction](https://data.nesfa.org/Recursion/recursive_A.htm) site:

> The narrator desires to be a fantasy writer and has made some strides in that direction. He encounters fantasy writer Harold Eldritch when he is speaking at Hofstra University. Eldritch is short, feisty, charismatic, and prolific. After the speech, the narrator talks to him and shakes his hand. From that time on he cannot write any fiction. Apparently, Eldritch has drained that mana from him by contact. Eldritch's mannerisms and characteristics are based upon an actual author—one who does not need other's mana.

Excerpts:

> A simple handshake. A ritual performed so often and with so little conscious thought as to be practically an instinctual reflex. Although the exact origin is difficult to pinpoint, there is a widespread belief that in its oldest form the handshake signified the handing of power from a god to an early Egyptian ruler. Centuries later, it was this magical aspect of the handshake that was so magnificently rendered on the ceiling of the Sistine Chapel. In Medieval times, it might mean anything from a friendly greeting to a quick check for concealed weapons. In the 21st Century, the handshake had evolved into an important social custom; a symbol of honor and good faith, it ‘sealed the deal.’ But could it be magic? What exactly was exchanged in that special moment of personal interaction - a little sweat, some exfoliated skin cells, a warm fuzzy feeling. What else?

> I waited patiently as the line crawled forth. Every so often, leaning out to check my progress, I would spy the great author himself seated at a cheap folding table at the end of the hallway. At last it was my turn. I must confess to a certain inotropic thumping of my heart as I stepped toward the table. I towered over him, but he smiled paternally up at me as I extended my hand. He extended his, and there it was, the long-awaited moment of contact. Our hands grappled firmly for a moment as if undertaking the first grip of an arm-wrestling match, and then it was over. Had I felt a little spark of electricity pass between us in that brief pressing of the flesh? A tingle surely, but was it really magic or simply the shag carpet and my sneakers talking? There was no time to contemplate that now, I was face to face with Harold Eldritch and the silence was growing uncomfortable. What to say? What to say?

> It’s ten years on now. I’m a modestly successful accountant at a small North Jersey firm. Needless to say, my great writing career did not go as planned. In fact, I don’t write at all any more. I haven’t penned a short story in eight or nine years. Not even a poem, a ditty or an ode. No, I’ll never be another Harold Eldritch. I’ll never have one best seller to my credit let alone a string of a hundred. He’s still pumping them out, magnificently working his old-school typewriter on the ranch in sunny CA, still speaking engagements to the thrill of young writers everywhere. Still shaking hands.

Comment: Thank you!  I had the decade right!

Comment: You're welcome!